# Edit on existing query to search if time is between start date and end date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Through a form the user selects a date + time and then when he submits it, the code run this query

```
ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `start`, :time )) < 2
```

that finds all the rows where the difference between `start` and selected date is less than 2.

However, I now added a new field `end` that holds the end date+time of the event.

My question is how should I edit my existing query to return all the rows that the selected date is between `start` and `end`?

This is the format of *selected*, *start* and *end* date+time: `2012-07-25 04:30`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN start AND end
```

To quote the manual about using `BETWEEN` with dates:

> For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE.

Comment: Thank you for this. In my case all inputs are like 2012-07-25 04:30. So do I need to use CAST() ?

Comment: If they're in the same format, and they are, then you do not need to use it.